# pandas.read_xml to also load the value of a parent attribute

Tags: pandas, xml

I have an XML file which is behind a .zip and its structure looks something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<sales>
  <forecast loc="Ohio">
    <hour>
      <time>1</time>
      <date>8/6/2023</date>
      <val>15000</val>
    </hour>
    <hour>
      <time>2</time>
      <date>8/6/2023</date>
      <val>14500</val>
    </hour>
  </forecast>
  <forecast loc="Texas">
    <hour>
      <time>1</time>
      <date>8/6/2023</date>
      <val>13000</val>
    </hour>
  </forecast>
</sales>
```

What I am trying to do is read it using [pandas.read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html). My ultimate goal would be getting this dataframe:

| date | time | val | loc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/6/2023 | 1 | 15000 | Ohio |
| 8/6/2023 | 2 | 14500 | Ohio |
| 8/6/2023 | 1 | 13000 | Texas |

The problem is with the `loc` column which I can not get by using this peace of code:
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_xml("URL_TO_MY_ZIP_FILE", ecoding='UTF-8', xpath='.//hour')
```

what it returns is the following (everything except for the value of parent's attribute):

| date | time | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/6/2023 | 1 | 15000 |
| 8/6/2023 | 2 | 14500 |
| 8/6/2023 | 1 | 13000 |

is there a way to modify my xpath expression somehow and also get the loc attribute value for each of my row (forecast) items? What I've also tried is :

```
pd.read_xml("URL_TO_MY_ZIP_FILE", ecoding='UTF-8', xpath='./forecast[@loc="*"]/hour')
and
pd.read_xml("URL_TO_MY_ZIP_FILE", ecoding='UTF-8', xpath='./forecast/')
```

but no success. I get an `Invalid expression` error or it just returns the same data frame (without location id).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with `xpath` or `iterparse`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71922600/including-parent-attributes-when-parsing-xml-using-pandas-read-xml

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do it with `read_xml()` directly (though will be happy to be proven wrong) so you may hare to resort to a more manual approach:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

sales = """your xl above"""
doc =  etree.XML(sales.encode())
rows = []
fcs = doc.xpath('//forecast')
for fc in fcs:
    for hour in fc:
        row = []
        row.append(fc.xpath('./@loc')[0])
        for dat in hour:            
            row.extend(dat.xpath('.//text()'))
        rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

The output should be your expected output though you ay hae to rearrange the colun order.